# Copy Word contents into Outlook

Tags: python, outlook, ms-word, win32com

I have a Word document with formatted text, images, and tables. You can manually copy its contents and insert into Outlook with no problems. How to do it in Python?

**My code:**

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open(your_doc_path)
contents = 'What here?'  # doc.Content?

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
# Create a new MailItem object
msg = outlook.CreateItem(0)

msg.Body = 'What here?'  # `contents` throws pywintypes.com_error
msg.Display(False)
```

**The closest problems:**

[Copy Word format into Outlook message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628208/copy-word-format-into-outlook-message)

[A word document's contents as the body of an email message](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ff6a5a9f-30db-4e14-be81-73f03b3b53d1/a-word-documents-contents-as-the-body-of-an-email-meassage?forum=outlookdev)

[How to paste into Outlook from Microsoft Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850485/how-to-paste-into-outlook-from-microsoft-word)

[Exporting rich text to outlook and keep formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245127/exporting-rich-text-to-outlook-and-keep-formatting)

**Does not work:**

1-Saving a Word doc as HTML (analogously RTF) and

```
with open(html_path, 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
    # Possible UnicodeDecodeError
    doc_body = f.read()

    msg.BodyFormat = 2  # olFormatHTML
    msg.Body = doc_body
```

2-Reading document.xml in the zipped Word document.

Possible way:

> The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of
>   the Word Document which represents the message body.

How to apply WordEditor via win32com?

Comment: I was able to copy contents of a RTF file, but without images. and the tables are shifted. For that, open the file in `'rb'` mode and set `msg.BodyFormat = 3  # olFormatRichText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Alina Li, here is the final solution:

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open(word_path)
doc.Content.Copy()
doc.Close()

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
# Create a new MailItem object
msg = outlook.CreateItem(0)
msg.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range(Start=0, End=0).Paste()

msg.Display(False)
```

Images, tables, format - everything is good.

Comment: Make sure that Outlook app is open when running this code.

Answer (score -1):

You could copy Word contents into Outlook with the below code:

```
import win32com.client
app=win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc=app.Documents.Open(r'D:\winGUI\test\1.doc')
doc.Content.Copy()
doc.Close()
```

Paste using the `Paste ()` method

Comment: Using `Paste()` method of what object? `msg.Body.Paste()` raises `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Paste'`

Comment: I figured out. It's `msg.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range(0).Paste()`.